# Promise.catch is swallowing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, callback, promise

I've done a lot of async coding in Node.js with callbacks and the excellent async library which works great. I'm trying to use a module that uses promises but I'm running into a problem where any errors thrown AFTER the promise are still bubbled up and caught by the promise error handler.

This makes it very difficult to debug errors as I have no idea where they will pop up and they can't be thrown and don't crash the app.

**Example code below**; all I want to do is to exit the promise chain and leave it behind once it has been resolved, rather than it catching all subsequent errors that aren't anything to do with it.

```
function one (input, callback) {

  doSomeAsyncWork(input)
  .then(function (result) {
    return callback(null, result);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    logError(err);
    return callback(err);
  });

}

function two (err, result) {

  if (err) { ... }

  var x = callAMethodThatThrows();
  ...

}

one('abc', two);
```

In this example, the method **callAMethodThatThrows()** throws an error, which gets bubbled up to the promise **catch()** block. This prevents the app from crashing and leaves it in an unknown state.

Any advice would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sorry about that - we're getting to fixing(1) the default behavior in Node. In the meanwhile I specced and [Petka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) added (with support from others) a hook for finding these errors:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, p) => {
    console.error(err); // print the error
});
```

Note that this might catch some false negatives if you're performing `.catch` asynchronously itself - in my experience that's very rare.

Also note that with promises your server typically *isn't* in an unknown state and you *can* and should attempt to recover from errors when it makes sense. Since promises all the way means throw-safe code you can have fine grained error handling.

Note that promises make the async library largely unneeded. If you still wish to use callbacks and just wish "those pesky promises" would leave you alone and let you keep writing callbacks, that's fine - promises are throw safe but you can escape that by executing things *off* the promise code:

```
myPromiseFn().then(v => {
    process.nextTick(() => cb(null, v)); // next tick, to escape the chain
}, e => process.nextTick(() => cb(e));
```

Note that fair promise libraries also come with a `asCallback` callback for converting the promise code to a node err-back callback.

(1) Some people claim there is no problem, go figure

Comment: Thanks Ben, this has helped. Currently our codebase is written using callbacks so it makes sense for us to stick with one way of doing things. I am eagerly awaiting the async/await keywords to land so we don't have to worry about these sorts of things!

Comment: @JoshCole async/await is just sugar for promises. Your answer (using nodeify) is fine - personally I'd do it with bluebird and `asCallback` but both are fine. In general it's not cool for a library to offer a promise API without any way to opt out of it.

Comment: That's useful to know. Still, if we're going to spend time refactoring our code I'd rather wait until we can have some sugar. Cheers.

Comment: Very late but could you please elaborate this "Note that this might catch some false negatives if you're performing .catch asynchronously itself - in my experience that's very rare."

Comment: We've fixed the default behavior a few years ago :]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ben's answer I discovered it's possible to convert a promise to a callback using a module such as [nodeify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeify). This allows us to keep all our code using callbacks, and avoids errors getting swallowed by the promise. Very useful.